# A quicker way to change owner/group recursively?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, terminal, chown

Currently, when I want to change owner/group recursively, I do this:

```
find . -type f -exec chown <owner>.<group> {} \;
find . -type d -exec chown <owner>.<group> {} \;
```

But that can take several minutes for each command. I heard that there was a way to do this so that it changes all the files at once (much faster), instead of one at a time, but I can't seem to find the info. Can that be done?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Use `chown`'s recursive option:

```
chown -R owner:group * .[^.]*
```

Specifying both `*` and `.[^.]*` will match all the files and directories that `find` would. The recommended separator nowadays is `:` instead of `.`. (As pointed out by [justins](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/218842/justins), using `.*` is unsafe since it can be expanded to include `.` and `..`, resulting in `chown` changing the ownership of the parent directory and all its subdirectories.)

If you want to change the current directory's ownership too, this can be simplified to

```
chown -R owner:group .
```

Answer (score 9):

For commands like `chown` that have their own recursion it is fastest to use that option:

```
 chown -R owner:group * .[^.]*
```

Warning! In some shells, the form `chown -R owner:group * .*` replaces owner in root directory / . Because `.*` means `../../../../root, ../bin ... etc`. All paths. However, the most widely used shell, *bash*, doesn't apply `.` and `..`, expanding patterns.

However it is useful to know that the main problem that slows down your use of `find` is that you invoke `chmown` on every single directory and file found. It is much quicker to use:

```
find . -type f -exec chown <owner>:<group> {} +
find . -type d -exec chown <owner>:<group> {} +
```

as each time `chown` is called with as many parameters as fit on the commandline.

That change works for other commands, that don't have a built-in recursion option like `chown`, as well. And it works (and improves speed) in situations where there is such a recursion option but you cannot use it (e.g. when using `chmod`, and you only want to change directories).